# Has NAB CEO taken up his entitlements of new shares early this year?

Tags: stocks, investing, australia, shares

Does anyone know whether the NAB CEO Andrew Thorburn has taken up all his entitlements for the new shares (i.e., increasing the amount of NAB shares he owns) during the capital raising early this year?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

National Australia Bank (ASX:NAB) undertook a pro rata accelerated renounceable entitlement offer (2 for 25 ordinary shares at $28.50).

If you have a look at the announcements for NAB for 2015:
http://www.asx.com.au/asx/statistics/announcements.do?by=asxCode&asxCode=NAB&timeframe=Y&year=2015

you'll notice a number of Appendix 3Y announcements.  These related to changes in directors shareholdings.

On 15 Jun 2015 there was an announcement "Appendix 3Y - Change of Director's Interest Notice X 11" that showed that Andrew Gregory Thorburn acquired 7214 ordinary shares (up from 90175) as a result of his participation in the offer.  The amount of shares indicates he participated fully.  His performance rights were unchanged since they were not subject to the offer.

Source: ASX web site